# momentjs - use user given string to check date difference

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm writing a simple chrome extension.

I need to check the difference between today and user given date.

My user writes the date as `dd/mm/yyyy` and it is saved in localstorage.

Then I use this snippet of code to check the difference:

```
var start = moment(new Date(dateFromLocalStorage));
console.log(start);
var today = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
counter.innerHTML = start.diff(today, 'days');
```

The console log returns this:

```
Moment{
  _d:Invalid Date
  _i:Invalid Date
  _isAMomentObject:true
  _isUTC:false
  _isValid:false
  _locale:Locale
  _pf:Object
  __proto__:Object
}
```

Is it possible to use the date as provided by my users?

Because of the invalid date, the result is NaN.

Thanks for any support on this.

Comment: `dateFromLocalStorage` how does it look ?

Comment: This is copied directly from the local storage as it is: 15/01/2014

Comment: Don't use the Date constructor to create a moment, as "parsing dates via the Date object is unreliable and inconsistent across platforms". See here: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost.

```
var start = moment(dateFromLocalStorage, "DD/MM/YYYY");
var today = moment();
var difference = today.diff(start, 'days');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

`var start = moment(new Date(dateFromLocalStorage));`

to

`var start = moment(dateFromLocalStorage,"DD/MM/YYYY");`

References :
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dateFromLocalStorage = "15/01/2014";
var start = moment(dateFromLocalStorage, "DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log(start);
var today = moment(new Date());
var diff = today.diff(start, 'days');
console.log(diff, 'days');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

look at this, you need to parse the date to a Date standar or use moment

Comment: yes it does look at the snippet, 15/01/2014 is not a Date available format

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
var a = moment('15/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
var b = moment(moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY');
var days = b.diff(a, 'days');
alert(days);
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/wL2f7q0w/78/)